# Folder error setting up WSDL in Matlab on mac

Tags: matlab, apache, wsdl, adoptopenjdk

I'm trying to set up WSDL tools in Matlab on a mac (following this tutorial: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/display-a-world-map.html).

The `matlab.wsdl.setWSDLToolPath('JDK',jdk,'CXF',cxf)` function needs to get the path for both openJDK and Apache-CXF. I have downloaded both of these, but am unsure what the correct path should be on a mac. The examples provided on the MathWorks website and forums all have examples of paths for a PC, but on a mac it is not clear to me what the actual program file would be.

I get errors along the lines of these:

```
Warning: The path '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/adoptopenjdk8/8,292:b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_8u292b10.pkg' has been
saved but the folder was not found. 
> In matlab.wsdl.setWSDLToolPath (line 107) 
Warning: The path '/Users/bricehen/Downloads/apache-cxf-3.4.6.tar.gz' has been saved but the folder was not found. 
> In matlab.wsdl.setWSDLToolPath (line 107)
```

This is the error if I provide the path to the downloaded packages themselves.

If I provide paths to the unpacked folders I get from the downloaded `pkg` or `tar.gz` files, I get errors along the lines of:

```
Error using matlab.wsdl.setWSDLToolPath>checkVersion (line 232)
The path '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/adoptopenjdk8/8,292:b10' does not seem to be a JDK folder.

Error in matlab.wsdl.setWSDLToolPath (line 119)
                            checkVersion(path, 'java', 'JDK', '-version', ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!